# What is the best way to copy a buffer and return a pointer to the next available element?

Tags: c

I have developed a function for copying elements from one `unsigned char` buffer to another. I designed the function to return a pointer to the *next available (empty)* element in the destination buffer. The point of doing that is so that I know where start writing to the destination buffer if I choose to call the function again and write more data to the destination buffer (from some other source buffer). Here is the function:

```
unsigned char *copyBuffer(unsigned char *sourceBuf,
                          unsigned char *destBuf, 
                          int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < size; ++i) {
        *(destBuf + i) = *(sourceBuf + i);
    };
            
    // return a pointer to the next unpopulated element in the dest buffer
    return (destBuf + i + 1);
}
```

The dilemma I have is that though this compiles fine, I think I may run into runtime issues because I may be referencing an out-of-bounds pointer once the destination buffer has been completely filled.

For example:

```
unsigned char destBuf[10];
unsigned char sourceBuf1[6];
unsigned char sourceBuf2[4];

unsigned char *pBuffer = NULL;

pBuffer = copyBuffer(sourceBuf1, destBuf, 6);
copyBuffer(sourceBuf2, pBuffer, 4);
```

After the second copy operation, won't the pointer returned be out of bounds because the last line of my function is

```
return (destBuf + i + 1);
```

How can I achieve the functionality that I'm seeking without having this issue? Or is there another way entirely to achieve this which is better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The return location is wrong. Your loop writes to `destBuff[0]` through `destBuff[size-1]` . The next writable location would simply be `destBuff + size`, not `destBuff + i + 1` (which is effectively `destBuff + size + 1`).

Comment: To avoid issues with overflows, you may want to pass in the size of the destination (and possibly the size of the source buffer, if it is not null-terminated). Then you can check as you're copying. I'd also suggest that if the source is larger than the destination, you return `NULL`. Then you can check the return value for `NULL` to determine if that has happened.

Comment: @WhozCraig isn't `destBuf + size` the same thing as `destBuf + i + 1` on the last iteration? For example, if size is 3, then (i = 2) on the last iteration, so they both end up being `return (destBuf + 3)`

Comment: Depending on the situation, very often the "best" way to copy data is to not copy it at all.

Comment: @RealTime-OS If `size` is `3`, then in order to fail the predicate `i < size`, `i` must be greater than or equal to `3`. At the end of your loop `i == size`.

Comment: if size = 3, for terminates at i =3 since 3 not lessthan 3, so, destBuf + i + 1 => destBuf + 3 + 1, where destBuf[3]  = '\0' and destBuf[4] is not in range

Comment: @RealTime-OS No, they're not the same. The loop terminated because `i < size` was *false*. Due to the structure of the loop (single-step incremental), that means `i == size` was *true* as the cause for breaking the loop. Therefore `i+1` is *not* equivalent to `size` after the loop completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add additional parameter showing the size of the buffer. Return value NULL indicates that the buffer is full.
2. `destBuf + i + 1` does not point to the next "free" character, only one after
3. use the correct type for size.

```
unsigned char* copyBuffer(const unsigned char *sourceBuf, unsigned char *destBuf, const size_t size, const size_t destbuffsize)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    memcpy(destBuf, sourceBuf, size <= destbuffsize ? size : destbuffsize);
    
    if(size < destbuffsize) result = destBuf + size;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your solution. An additional questions I have is, is a statement like the following valid :  destPointer = copyBuffer(sourceBuf, destPointer, size, destbuffsize); ? Essentially reassigning destBuf to the value returned by the function, while also using the current destBuf value as an argument to the function? Does this violate C in any way? I am trying to avoid creating an extra pointer variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your approach: while it is OK to return a pointer one past the address of the last element of an array, you actually return a pointer 1 byte beyond the end. Is this the intent? `i` is incremented after the last copy so `buf + i` points to the next available element.

Note also these remarks:

- `sourceBuf` should be declared as `const unsigned char *` as you do not modify the source buffer.
- the `;` after the body of the `for` loop is redundant, remove it.
- the lonely `i` in the first clause of the `for` is useless and confusing.
- I would suggest using `size_t` for the type of `size` and `i`
- the order of arguments is confusing as it is the opposite of that of `memcpy`.

Here is a modified version:

```
unsigned char *copyBuffer(unsigned char *destBuf,
                          const unsigned char *sourceBuf,
                          size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        destBuf[i] = sourceBuf[i];
    }
            
    // return a pointer to the next unpopulated element in the dest buffer
    return destBuf + i;
}
```

Incrementing the pointers allows for a simpler version:

```
unsigned char *copyBuffer(unsigned char *destBuf,
                          const unsigned char *sourceBuf,
                          size_t size)
{
    while (size --> 0) {
        *destBuf++ = *sourceBuf++;
    }
    // return a pointer to the next unpopulated element in the dest buffer
    return destBuf;
}
```

This above function has the same behavior as `mempcpy()` available in the GNU libC and some other ones:

```
void *mempcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

You should consider using this one as it is optimized on systems that support it and can be easily added on systems lacking it.